# API request succeds but catch is executed instead of then?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, try-catch

I have this weird error in my React app at the moment. I am sending an api request and I want to do something if it succeeds and something else if I get an error back. The api requests succeeds, the post is getting approved, but the catch clause is executed instead of then.

Can you see something in this code that might make that happen?

The request which I am talking about is the Request.post one... the large one that ecompasses a few other requests.

```
    export const approvePostSubmission = (post, date) => dispatch => {
  const label = `${post.campaign_product_name} on ${moment(date).format('LL')}`;

  if (post.post_type === 3) {
    dispatch(sendGoogleEvent(GOOGLE_EVENT.STORY.APPROVE, label));
  } else {
    dispatch(sendGoogleEvent(GOOGLE_EVENT.POST.APPROVE, label));
  }

  dispatch({
    type: APPROVE_POST_PENDING,
  });

  return Request.post(
    API_ENDPOINT.POST_APPROVE(post.id),
    { publish_at: date },
    false
  )
    .then(response => {
      const { selectedContent } = store.getState().inbox;

      dispatch(getUserWallet());

      dispatch({
        type: APPROVE_POST_SUCCESS,
      });

      const getPostTypeText = post_type => {
        switch (post_type) {
          case 3:
            return 'Story';
          case 4:
            return 'IGTV Post';
          case 5:
            return 'Carousel';
          case 6:
            return 'IG Live';
          default:
            return 'Post';
        }
      };

      const postType = getPostTypeText(selectedContent.post.post_type);

      setTimeout(() => {
        toast.show(
          <p>
            {`Woo! You approved a ${postType}! It will be published on `}
            <RouterLink
              to="/calendar"
              color="#0dd36b"
              onClick={e => toast.hide()}
            >
              {`${moment(date).format('LL')} `}
            </RouterLink>
          </p>,
          {
            type: 'success',
            dismiss: true,
          }
        );
      }, 100);

      // Send slack bot message
      Request.post(`${SLACKBOT.URL}/new-post`, {
        post_status: 1,
        post_type: selectedContent.post.post_type,
        post_id: selectedContent.post.id,
        campaign_name: selectedContent.post.campaign_product_name,
        influencer_id: selectedContent.influencer.id,
        influencer_name: selectedContent.influencer.full_name,
        campaign_id: selectedContent.post.campaign_id,
        post_image: selectedContent.post.image_url,
        slack_channel: SLACKBOT.CHANNELS.NEW_POST,
      })
        .then(data => {})
        .catch(err => console.error(err));

      return response;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch({
          type: APPROVE_POST_FAIL_SHOW_ERR,
          payload: !!err.response
            ? err.response.data.message
            : 'Unable to approve post!',
        });

        !!err.response &&
          toast.show(
            `${err.response.data.message || err.response.data.error} `,
            { type: 'fail' }
          );
        setTimeout(() => {
          dispatch({
            type: APPROVE_POST_FAIL,
          });
        }, 3000);
      }, 500);
    });
};
```

Comment: It's probably executed _additionally_ to your `then` because you have an error inside your `then`. Check the `err` that you get in the `catch` and edit the value of `err.stack` into your question please.

Comment: (as a reminder: `promise.then(a, b)` will run `a` for success or  `b` for failure, and any errors inside `a` or `b` are not handled and reject the whole promise chain, but `promise.then(a).catch(b)` is **not** the same, it will run `b` if the promise was rejected but also if `a` itself would throw an error (since that would make the promise returned by `promise.then(a)` be rejected), and only an error in `b` would reject the whole promise chain.)

Comment: @CherryDT thank you for responding. I did have a vague idea that, that may be it. I started adding things from top to bottom and I find that the  then stops working after this part     dispatch({
        type: APPROVE_POST_SUCCESS,
      });    . Would you have any idea why? I

Comment: Can you please do what I wrote in my first message, see what error you get in the catch clause and copy the value of `err.stack` into your question? That would be more effective than guessing. Thank you. (also, did you try setting a breakpoint at the start of the function in a debugger and then enabling breaking at caught exceptions before continuing execution? You should also stop at the exception this way.)

Comment: @CherryDT thank you very much for your help, I analyzed what I was doing in my reducer when that action type was dispatched and there was a small error in my logic for manipulatng the state that produced this issue, thanks so much for you help!!